# Query: Will Ubuntu installation delete my data?

Tags: 20.04

If I install Ubuntu on my Windows 10 desktop, will it erase all of my current existing data from C: or D: Drive? If not, from where will it consume the disk space??

Answer (score 1):

What an installation of Ubuntu does on your computer, is your choice. You determine what happens.

By default, the installer will offer options to either 1) install Ubuntu next to Windows, and 2) use the entire disk. Optie 1) will not delete data, but try to shrink your partition if needed. Option 2 will erase the entire disk. The installer also allows for manual partitioning.

Whatever you do, make sure you have a good and up to date backup of your existing data before doing any change on your computer. There is always a certain risk that something goes wrong. You may never take a risk to loose your personal files. A good backup safeguards you against that.

Comment: Thanks-a-lot.. Really appreciate your help...

Answer (score 1):

That depends on which installation option you choose. The options are (names according to my memory):

- Use full disk - will delete every thing on the disk
- Install beside Windows - will let you choose free space or reduce size of existion partition (drive, C: D: ..).
- Something else - Lets you handle the partitioning your self.

The preferred way is, if you don't have free unassigned space on your disk, to reduce an existing partition with Windows tools, then boot the installer and choose the free space.